# Entity Framework : Cannot evaluate expression because the code of the current method is optimized.

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework

I'm using Entity framework 6 ( DBContext ) and VB.net 2013
I have this code :

```
Partial Public Class Myentities
Inherits DbContext
Implements IObjectContextAdapter
Public ReadOnly Property ObjectContext() As ObjectContext Implements IObjectContextAdapter.ObjectContext
    Get
        Dim objectContext__1 = TryCast(Me, IObjectContextAdapter)
        If objectContext__1 IsNot Nothing Then
            Return TryCast(Me, IObjectContextAdapter).ObjectContext
        Else
            Return Nothing
        End If
    End Get
End Property

  Public Sub New(connectionString As String)
    MyBase.New("name=MyEntities")
    Database.Connection.ConnectionString = connectionString
End Sub
End class
```

.......

```
dim context as new Myentities
```

But I get this error :

```
Cannot evaluate expression because the code of the current method is optimized.
```

What's the problem ?

Thank you !

Comment: No need to cast this object twice - if it cast on the first call use that object.

Comment: This message usually occurs when you are running in Release instead of Debug and the compiler optimized out the line. In this case, perhaps you aren't using context anywhere. Switch to Debug and see if you get the same message.